# How convert below Java for loop to stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been trying to use `map()` to do the first two steps but I'm not quite sure how to get the index i that represents the count of the current iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
    String country = carList.get(i).getCountry();
    List<Integer> indexes = carsToIndexMap.getOrDefault(country, new ArrayList<>());
    indexes.add(i);
    carsToIndexMap.put(country, indexes);
}
```

I've been trying something like this:

```
carList.stream()
    .map(p -> p.getCountry())
    .map(country -> carsToIndexMap.getOrDefault(country, new ArrayList<>()))
```

Comment: You need more detail.  What does the existing map look like?  What does the final output look like based on input?  And please include the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you seem to be looking for a grouping by `country` with `indexes` of the cars processed corresponding to it. This can be achieved by making use of `IntStream` with the range of `carList` size and `groupingBy` collector.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> carsToIndexMap = IntStream.range(0, carList.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> carList.get(i).getCountry()));
```

*Suggestion*: Your variable name should indicate that the key is country and not cars, something like `countryIndices`.